# getting php session variable in js file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, editablegrid

I have a php file with a php if statement that generates a php session variable for a mySQL table name. I need to access this table name is a javascript file demo.js. Any ideas would be great.

PHP Code Snip-it:

```
$fcyclestartdate = $_POST['CycleStartDate'];
$fcycleenddate = $_POST['CycleEndDate'];
$_SESSION["paycycletable"] = "PCR_".str_replace("-", "", $fcyclestartdate)."_".str_replace("-", "", $fcycleenddate);
```

js file code Snip-it:

```
function DatabaseGrid() 
{ 
    this.editableGrid = new EditableGrid("demo", {//Variable table name must go where "demo" is
        enableSort: true,
        // define the number of row visible by page
        pageSize: 50,
        // Once the table is displayed, we update the paginator state
        tableRendered:  function() {  updatePaginator(this); },
        tableLoaded: function() { datagrid.initializeGrid(this); },
        modelChanged: function(rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row) {
            updateCellValue(this, rowIndex, columnIndex, oldValue, newValue, row);
        }
    });
    this.fetchGrid();   
}
```

Comment: Your JS file would need to be executed as PHP, probably just change the extension and then use `<?php echo $_SESSION["paycycletable"]; ?>` in the JS instead of demo.

Comment: this doesnt work due to the calls of the js functions in the js file.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: If file cannot be changed to php file then as far as I know your only option remains loading session value using ajax.

Comment: If it's not high security, you might want to set a `$_COOKIE` instead of a `$_SESSION`. JS can then read from the cookie afterwords.

Comment: While the application is high security the variable being passed is not. Thanks for this information. and your help

Answer (score 0):

Save the table name in JS global space.

In your php code:

```
echo "<script> paycycletable='" . $_SESSION["paycycletable"] . "'</script>";
```

Now you have this variable anywhere in your JS

```
this.editableGrid = new EditableGrid(paycycletable, {...
```